# Life Cycle Management for Azure File Share

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, fileshare, storage-file-share

I just found that there is not Life Cycle Management support for a file share in a blob storage. What is a good way to regularly delete files from a file share? Logic App? Azure function? It should be also cost sensitive.

Comment: Charbel Nemnom has a blog post one implementing this: https://charbelnemnom.com/move-files-between-azure-file-share-tiers/

Answer (score 1):

I´d say both Function or Logic Apps are proper solutions.

Cost for functions depends on the number of executions and the execution time. You get 1 million free executions per month and the first 400GB/s are also free. But you have to code.